# When to use "disculpe" instead of "perdón"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, sinónimos

Are *disculpe* and *perdón* 100% interchangeable? If not, when should I use one versus another?

If I accidentally bumped someone as I walked by them would I say "Disculpe", "Perdón", or just "Lo siento"?

Comment: Hice un "merge" de esta pregunta con [What is the difference among “perdón”, “disculpa” and “lo siento”?](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/15424/1674)